# cache problems (cshtml, jquery, AngularJS)

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, caching, browser-cache

Okay here we go, this might take a bit of back and forth because I'm not sure where to begin - the amount of code that builds the foundation to this page is rather excessive so I won't post it all.

I'm having a cache issue, where by - on one of my pages I have a checkbox tree list that allows the user to select from a number of options in the search page;

Now when a user selects an option from the checkbox tree list, this item carries across and returns results on the product page.

The issue I'm having is that if the user navigates back using the browser buttons, and changes the option selected in the checkbox tree list, then goes back to the product page, the initial selection remains rather than the new selection - this is definitely down to the page being cached - if you refresh and clear cache the new selection appears.

I've tried stopping the page from being cached with something like :

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

We use AngularJS to build the product page so I've tried variations on

```html
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

And we use jQuery to build the navigation buttons so I've tried adding jquery calls using .removeData or this sort of thing :

```html
$.ajax({
url: 'test.html',
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$('#results').append(html);
}
});
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this cache issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think there are not enough informations to answer you. The forward button of the browser reloads the page (or history state) with the parameters it had when you visited it. The behaviour for parameters depends on different things, how are these parameters passed to the page (like if passed by URL, they won't be updated), are the back/forward buttons behaviour overriden by your application tu use states instead of page reloads, etc.

Comment: The parameters are passed by URL, as far as I know there is nothing in our codebase that would override the browser buttons- but there are a lot of different elements that go into these pages, we make a call to two databases and our booking engine on both the search page and the product page to deliver relevant results -
I'd add the code for the page but there is quite a lot of it - I don't want to drown you guys haha!

Comment: What I need is a way of force refreshing the page once an option is changed, or a way of not caching to begin with but on the one page only ?

Comment: There is a strong chance that angular overrides these buttons to introduce state changes instead of page reloads, never looked at it yet. To mess with the browser history, you can use the functions `history.pushState / history.replaceState` and the event `window.onpopstate`, at least to take a look at what's there as a start. There might be angular functions specific for that too

Comment: Ahh you're a babe thank you, I'll look into that! I'm a bit lost here to be honest haha!

Comment: you're welcome, if i have time i'll post examples, i did it already in a project but the functions are complex and need to be simplified for an example

Comment: Thanks lovely  :) that would be very much appreciated!